# Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my table? I cannot PDFtexify it

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Just staying up late doing my assignment. I have noticed that despite all the previous work I did and comparing it with what I have done now, I can't seem to find my flaw in this table.

If you can shed some light on this that would be much appreciated!

```
\begin{tabular} {c|l|l} \hline
                        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Math 2024 assessment tasks}          \\ \hline 
    Category            & Content                                 & Week Due\\ \hline
    Assignments         & 1. Mathematical Typesetting             & Week 4
                        & 2. Cultural Awareness                   & Week 7
                        & 3. Good Mathematical Writing            & Week 10
                        & 4. Career Planning                      & Week 11\\ \hline
    Expository Paper    & Talk 1: 5 minutes                       & Week 5
                        & Draft of written paper                  & Week 6
                        & Written paper                           & Week 12
                        & Talk 2: 10 minutes                      & Week 13\\ \hline
    Minitalks           & HMC Math Fun Facts                      & throughout \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

The error I am having is

```
1.99       &
                 2. cultural awareness                & week 7
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to TeX.SX. There's very little to be gained from also including an image of your code. Instead, if you want the syntax highlighting, etc., simply highlight your code and press ctrl+k, or use the code sample button (5th from the left, the one that looks like {})

Comment: There are quite a number of end-of-line commands `\\ ` missing.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is so much to be learnt with this as I have no clue what syntax highlighting and all that means. But  I will look into it. And also thank you, that seems to be all i was missing

Comment: @zyzztheturtle the syntax highlighting is just the different colours used in your code, like the red `{}`s and the blue `&`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All errors disappear when the proper end-of-line commands are added in. The resulting code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} {c|l|l} \hline
                        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Math 2024 assessment tasks}          \\ \hline 
    Category            & Content                                 & Week Due\\ \hline
    Assignments         & 1. Mathematical Typesetting             & Week 4 \\
                        & 2. Cultural Awareness                   & Week 7 \\
                        & 3. Good Mathematical Writing            & Week 10 \\
                        & 4. Career Planning                      & Week 11\\ \hline
    Expository Paper    & Talk 1: 5 minutes                       & Week 5 \\
                        & Draft of written paper                  & Week 6 \\
                        & Written paper                           & Week 12 \\
                        & Talk 2: 10 minutes                      & Week 13\\ \hline
    Minitalks           & HMC Math Fun Facts                      & throughout \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting table is

[image]

And so, the lesson is: always, always, *always* make sure you've got the end of line commands in your tables.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

As addition to heather's solution. Here is the `booktabs` version:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Math 2024 assessment tasks}\label{tab:Math2024}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        Category  & Content                       & Week Due \\ 
        \midrule
        Assignments & 1.\ Mathematical Typesetting & Week 4 \\
        & 2.\ Cultural Awareness                   & Week 7 \\
        & 3.\ Good Mathematical Writing            & Week 10 \\
        & 4.\ Career Planning                      & Week 11 \\ \midrule
        Expository Paper & Talk 1: 5 minutes      & Week 5 \\
        & Draft of written paper                  & Week 6 \\
        & Written paper                           & Week 12 \\
        & Talk 2: 10 minutes                      & Week 13 \\ \midrule
        Minitalks & HMC Math Fun Facts & throughout \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realised it.. Was too busy debugging other places and left such a silly mistake. Thank you so much

Comment: @zyzztheturtle You are very welcome.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, very nice solution...+1. Wish I'd thought of it. =)